# How to convert a RGB image to a two dimensional image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I have a RGB image called `imrgb`, the size of which is `320*512*3`.
I want to know how to convert it to a two dimensional image?
I saw some colorful images, but they are still two dimensional instead
of three dimensional. Can anyone tell me how to convert it to a 
two-dimensional image but still looks colorful?

[image]

Comment: @Benoit_11,  there is a problem, the map I get from [X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb,256) is totally different from the "color_map" I have. How to fix this problem?

Comment: what is the type of your image? Is it uint8, uint16?

Comment: @Benoit_11, the result for my X is 320*512 uint8. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood right you can store the image data as a 2D array and use a colormap to assign it colors, displaying it as a "colorful" image. In this case the colormap will be a `Nx3` array where each row corresponds to an index present (or not) in the image data. So if the colormap is a 256x3 array, for example, the image will be made of indices ranging from 0 to 255.

For example, let's consider the peppers.png demo image that ships with Matlab. Let's read and use the `rgb2ind` function to store the image data in variable `X` and its associated colormap in variable `map`.

```
a = imread('peppers.png');
[X,map] = rgb2ind(a,256);
```

If we ask the size of `X`, we get:

```
ans =

   384   512
```

So a 2D variable, even though the original image (`a`) was 3D (rgb).

If we wish to display this 2D data as a colorful we need to provide a suitable colormap. For instance, we can use the original colormap (stored in `map`) in order to get the following:

```
image(X)
colormap(map)
axis off
```

[image]

or we can use any other colormap of our choice.

For example:

```
image(X)
colormap(jet(200)) %// The size can be different than the original colormap
axis off
```

yielding:

[image]

So as you see the image looks 3D but the data is actually 2D.

Is this what you meant?

Comment: My data contains: color_map = 64*3 and imrgb = 320*512*3, but I do not have the original picture. How can I get X? Is X a matrix or a vector?

Comment: `X` is a matrix which will be 320*512. Try `[X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb,256)`

Comment: my color_map = 64*3. shouldn't I try: [X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb, 64)??

Comment: there is a problem, the map I get from [X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb,256) is totally different from the "color_map" I have. How to fix this problem?